# Is there a way I can automate moving files from into different locations using an if/ else statement in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I have a Matlab script that looks at information in a .xsl file and a DICOM file. I have recorded information on both files that needs to match. I've created a script that can review the information on both files and in an if/else statement it will display "Perfect Match", "Error 1", "Error 2". After that, I typically manually move the files to their respective folders.

However, I have recently gotten a hold of a lot of files that I need to perform this validation. Instead of manually moving the files is there a way I can automate this, hopefully by coupling it with the if/else statement? Here is a snippet of the code:
EDIT: I was told in the comment that my code provided wasn't sufficient enough so I have added more to it

```
clear;clc
Mosaiq_missing=[];Mismatch_dose_plan=[];no_plan=[];false_dose=[];


dirpat='C:\Users\X\Desktop\pts\';
[patnamen,~]=getfil(dirpat);

dirloc='C:\Users\X\Desktop\MOSAIQ_values.xlsx';
MOSAIQ=readtable(dirloc);
% MOSAIQ.ida=cellstr(num2str(MOSAIQ.ida));
oma=MOSAIQ(ismember(MOSAIQ.ida, patnamen),:);

co=[2 2 2 2 2 2];dc=1;
for pp=1:length(patnamen)
    clearvars -except dirpat patnamen dc pp Mosaiq_missing Mismatch_dose_plan no_plan false_dose wrong_dose_dir repeat oma oma_namen
    mismatch=0; hl=0;
    patientname=patnamen{pp};

    if ismember(patientname,oma.ida)
        display(['loading patient: ',patientname])
        dirloc=[fullfile(dirpat,patientname),'\'];
        pa = genpath(dirloc);
        splitfil=regexp(pa,'\;','split')';

% read dose plan locations 
     DOSEplek=cellfun(@isempty,regexp(splitfil,'DOSE'))==0;
     PLANplek=cellfun(@isempty,regexp(splitfil,'PLAN'))==0; 
     DOSE=splitfil(DOSEplek);
     PLAN=splitfil(PLANplek);


     if sum(PLANplek)>0
        [RTplan_files,~]=getfil(PLAN{1});

        for pl=1:length(RTplan_files)
            info=dicominfo(fullfile(PLAN{1},RTplan_files{pl}));

            beam_name=cell(length(fieldnames(  info.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence)),1);
            BeamMetersets=nan(length(fieldnames(  info.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence)),1);


            for p=1:length(fieldnames(   info.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence))
            BeamMetersets(p)=info.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence.(['Item_',num2str(p)]).BeamMeterset;
            beam_name(p)={info.BeamSequence.(['Item_',num2str(p)]).BeamDescription};
            end
            fraction_number=info.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.NumberOfFractionsPlanned;


        end

        %match to MOSAIQ_EXCEL_FILE
        % This is where things get separated, So I assume this is where movefile code would go
                loc=ismember(oma.ida,patientname);%cellfun(@isempty,regexpi(oma_namen,patientnaam))==0;
                MOSAIQ_sel=table2cell(oma(loc,:));

                if size(MOSAIQ_sel,1)==size(BeamMetersets,1)

                    if sum(~ismember(BeamMetersets,cell2mat(MOSAIQ_sel(:,10))))==0
                        disp('Perfect Match!!!')

                    else
                        disp('Error1')
                        BeamMetersets
                        mosaiq_beam_values=cell2mat(MOSAIQ_sel(:,10))

                    end

                else
                    disp('Error 2')

                end





     end
    end
end
```

I tried using movefile but I couldn't get it to work. I wanted the file to move to a location like:
'C:\Users\X\Desktop\PerfectMatch\'
'C:\Users\X\Desktop\Error1\'
'C:\Users\X\Desktop\Error2\'

Comment: What are your problems implementing this? I guess the right function is not difficult to find: `movefile`

Comment: there is a dangling "else" in the code you've shown. Also it is not a minimal working example, as `BeamMetersets` and `MOSAIQ_sel` are not defined. Try creating a small script to demonstrate your attempt, I'm guessing it will make yourself solve your problem, if it doesn't then try updating this question. But indeed, `movefile` or `copyfile` should provide you with what you need.

Comment: I tried using `movefile` but it didn't work. This is a sample of how I modified the code: `else
    disp('ERROR 1')
    BeamMetersets
    mosaiq_beam_values=cell2mat(MOSAIQ_sel(:,10))
movefile('C:\Users\example\ERROR1') `
That didnt move any files.